# Как перебрать все элемента списка и проверить у них наличие класса?

Tags: javascript

Есть список:

```
<ul>
    <li class="n">Текст</li>
    <li class="lc">текст</li>
    <li class="ac">текст</li>
    <li class="s">текст</li>
</ul>
```

Перебираю так:

```
let m = document.querySelector('ul');
let li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
[].forEach.call(m, function(li) {
    if(this.classList.contains('active')) {
        if(this.classList.contains('ac')) {
            // действие
        }
    }
});
```

Но ничего не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m` - не список, `li` - список.

```
li.forEach(function(item) {
  if (item.classList.contains('active') && item.classList.contains('ac')) {
    // действие
  }
});
```

Comment: Почему-то отказывается работать. Выдает ошибку именно в строке if (this.classList.contains('active') && this.classList.contains('ac')) {

Comment: @Frontender Пардон, не `this`, а `item`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('li')].forEach(node => {
  if (node.classList.contains('ac') && node.classList.contains('active')) {
    console.log(node);
    console.log('do something...');
  }
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="n">Текст</li>
  <li class="lc">текст</li>
  <li class="ac active">текст trigger</li>
  <li class="s">текст</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Нужно именно чтобы у класса ac еще присутствовал класс active

Comment: @Frontender, обновил

Answer (score 0):

```js
for (const li of document.querySelectorAll('ul li')) {
  if (li.matches('.ac.active')) {
    console.log(li.outerHTML);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="n">Текст</li>
  <li class="lc">текст</li>
  <li class="ac active">текст</li>
  <li class="s">текст</li>
</ul>
```